# Google login in swift

Tags: swift, google-signin

I want login with google but I can't get user last name...

how to get user first name, last name?

i use this code:

```
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name

            let email = user.profile.email


            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                "ToggleAuthUINotification",
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(name)"])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                "ToggleAuthUINotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "name" Filed contains First name and Last name

Example "name" = Alen Smith

Then First name = Alen and Last Name = Smith

Otherwise no way to get First and last name using google login in IOS.